# Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.indexOf called on null or undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why am I getting this error?
Error from the chrome's console...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.indexOf called on null or undefined
    at indexOf (<anonymous>)
    at Function.c.inArray (zepto.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (index.html:97)
    at HTMLDivElement.j (zepto.js:2)
c.inArray @ zepto.js:2
(anonymous) @ index.html:97
j @ zepto.js:2
```

And this is the code on and after the 97th line.

```
if ($.inArray($("#recipient-email").val(), recipientList) == -1) {
    recipientList.push($("#recipient-email").val());

                localStorage.setItem(
                  "recipient-list",
                  JSON.stringify(recipientList)
                );
```

Comment: Just a cursory glance it sounds like the array doesn't exist before the indexOf is called on it.

Comment: Could you out to console `recipientList`? just add `console.log(recipientList);` before if...

Comment: Under the hood inArray is using indexOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your code is fine, but the problem is at another point. As I see, you are using `jQuery` and sometimes it doesn't parse / grab results from `"#recipient-email"` div or so.

But it also doesn't return an empty array of `Array.prototype` itself and as a result, any `Array.prototype` method will return you the following error.

You should add some code for handling such scenario, like:

I don't know in which variable your array is stored, but I guess you would understand my logic.

```
if ($.inArray($("#recipient-email").val(), recipientList) === null) {
  $.inArray($("#recipient-email").val(), recipientList) === []
}
```